# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading text file

Tags: java, io

I am able to read a file using a Scanner. When the return type is void, I am able to read and print the data to the console, however, immediately afterward it throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Ideally, I want to return as a string array, however, I only get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. In both cases, the exception is thrown at the line cancers[j] = input.nextLine(). I have already made sure the size of the array is correct. When I do not hardcode the size of it, then the compiler throws a NullPointerException at the same line (which makes sense since the size of the array is not declared).

I need the method to return a string array as I have to do additional manipulations to it.

```
public String[] readCancer() {
       cancers = new String[21];
    int j = 0;
        try {
        input = new Scanner(myData);
        String result;
        while(input.hasNext()) {

            ++j;
            cancers[j] = input.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(cancers[j]);
         }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfx) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Txt file could not be found");
    }
   return cancers;
}
```

I tried re-writing the method in a slightly different way but I get the same error, only this time it is at output[i] = result;

```
public String[] readCancers() {
    FileInputStream fis;
    DataInputStream dis;
    BufferedReader br;
    InputStreamReader isr;
    String result;
    String[] output = new String[21];
    int i = 0;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myData);
        dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(dis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while((result = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ++i;
            output[i] = result;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfx) {
        fnfx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You're incrementing j and i before you do anything with them. So your array starts at 1 instead of 0 giving you only 20 instead of 21 array elements. I'm assuming your file has 21 items and so when the 21st item is added, it goes out of bounds.

Comment: Doing something like cancers[j++]; will give you the effect of adding an element at cancers[j] and then incrementing j for the next time around. PS I hope you're doing medical stuff, otherwise cancers is a horrible variable name.

Comment: Dude, can you post your text file so that we know how many lines there are in the text file ?

Comment: @nickecarlo your suggestion worked brilliantly! The text file contains information for various cancer types, otherwise I agree it would have been a horrible name.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi my text file spans from lines 1 to 22.

Comment: Ok, which means your array is out of sufficient space. Means your array should be String[22];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know how many elements your file has but I'm assuming you have 21 elements and so you need a 21 element array. You've declared an array of 21 elements but the following code:

```
 ++j;
```

Means the following:

```
 j = j+1;
```

And then you add an element to your array using j which results in you skipping j = 0 completely and the 21st item tries to get placed at the 22nd element of the array, which is out of bounds. What you might want is something like this:

```
 cancers[j];
 j++;
```

Or:

```
 cancers[j++];
```

That way you're not going to go out of bounds. If you have more than 21 items then I'd suggest you increase the array size.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly! I feel a bit silly actually for something that obvious but I have to learn to think over my coding logic with a finer comb.

Comment: It happens. The more you code the more you'll get used to these practices and these mistakes. Have fun with your project and mark the answer accepted if your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters to your question: it can be an off-by-one type error, because you skipped the first array element. But once you have a fixed size array to read in, you'd have to bound check the value of i or j in the while loop in any case: `while(input.hasNext() && j < 20)` or `while((result = br.readLine()) != null && i < 21)`.
Then after the loop check if there would be any extra input, that may indicate an error, you have to handle that.